# Interview question, testing a sorting network

Tags: digital-logic, vlsi, interview-questions

Here is a question that I stumbled upon:

http://asicdigitaldesign.wordpress.com/2007/06/08/puzzle-4-the-min-max-question/

MinMax2 is a component with 2 inputs, A and B, and 2 outputs, Max and Min. You guessed it, you connect 2 numbers at the inputs and the component drives the Max output with the bigger of the two and the Min output with the smaller of the two.

Your job is to design a component MinMax4, with 4 inputs and 4 outputs, which sorts the 4 numbers using only MinMax2 components. Try to use as few MinMax2 components as possible.

Here is the solution:
http://asicdigitaldesign.wordpress.com/2007/06/24/puzzle-4-solution/

I succeeded in solving it, but what I didn't successfully answer is: how many different input sequences are needed to verify the logical behavior of MinMax4?

The obvious answer is $4!$, but as I understand there is a more minimal solution.

Comment: "not a real question"?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Posts here can be closed if they're considered not a real question. The idea of this forum is that you ask a question and users answer it, where it's a plus if this brings useful information for the community. It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I am asking how to check that system is working.So its pretty real I think

Comment: it's a *good* question, but it's a mathy, computer-sciency kind of question, which is likely to get it migrated ..

Comment: i have asked it on stackoverflow and didn't received answer there.Does anyone know some other forum?

Comment: I think it's on-topic as a VLSI/FPGA question, unless interview questions are off-topic.

Comment: We don't have anything against interview questions, they fall in the same category as homework questions. It is more about the content of the question then where the question came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is ambiguous, although sometimes interview questions are intentionally ambiguous to prompt a discussion of the ambiguities.

One way to look at it is, if you are verifying a design for a 4-input sorting network, how many input sequences are needed to be sure the implementation is correct. If you don't know anything about how it's implemented, then you need to test all $4!$ permutations of four values to be absolutely certain the implementation is correct.

Another way to look at it is, if you manufacture the circuit, how many input sequences do you need to apply to each device during testing to be sure the circuit was manufactured correctly. In this case you would usually take the design as a given, so you don't need to cover all $4!$ permutations, you just need enough inputs to cover the interesting cases for each element of the circuit. I'm guessing this was the intention of the question, and I'm guessing that only two cases are considered interesting for each MinMax2 component (A>B and A<B). There's also the A=B case, but you can argue the behavior of the MinMax2 is a don't-care when A=B.

This isn't realistic, since in practice you would need more than two cases to make sure all of the transistors and wires inside the MinMax2 component were manufactured correctly. But I'll assume that we're just trying to cover two cases for each MinMax2.

In that case, if the inputs are A through D where A < B < C < D, then only two inputs are necessary to cover both cases for each MinMax2: A, C, B, D and D, C, B, A. The first covers the "no-swap" case for each MinMax2, and the second covers the "swap" case for each MinMax2.